# Why I have to mount /dev /dev/pts /proc /run when I have to modify my GRUB config from a Live USB?

Tags: linux, boot, grub

As the title says, why I have to do that (other than `chroot`ing to my device) to change my GRUB CFG from a LiveUSB image?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Reference: [Click Me!](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2036730) I had the same error (`cannot find device for /` and that link helped me to solve my problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't if all you want to do is change your `grub.cfg`. You can just mount the `/` partition, `chroot` to it and make the changes you need.

You *do* need to mount the other directories if you want `grub` to autodetect any other installed operating systems since it needs access to those directories to be able to properly probe the system. By mounting them under your `chroot` environment, you mimic your installed system and trick `grub` into thinking it is running from that installed system.

---

EDIT: The directories you listed are needed because in order for GRUB to probe installed systems, it will need access to the devices (`/dev`) and to information about system memory, devices mounted, hardware configuration (`/proc`). I don't see why you need `/run` but that is a relatively [new addition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13972/22222) to Linux and I am not very familiar with it.

Comment: I needed to probe all the other OSes on my PC. But why are those NEEDED?

Comment: @Krishath see update.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Mounting it in my "original" box makes it available on my chroot environment then? Why I had to chroot to my system to make it work?

Comment: @Krishath Read up on [`chroot`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_Root). It creates a virtual environment where after you `chroot foo` the system acts as though `foo` were `/`. That is why with `chroot` you can mount an installed system and behave as though you had booted into it. Otherwise, any changes you made would only affect the LiveCD and not your installed system.